# Foundation Grid System Issue

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I am developing website via Foundation. But my grid system is not working properly. Whenever I resize my browser width to 1596px, 1440px and 1333px; grid system is not working properly. I put the my source code to

Codepen:

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/vefali/full/GpRMeo/)

I got a screenshot video of my scren.

[Youtube](https://youtu.be/pfWTmsip-gw)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="google" value="notranslate">


  <title>Foundation</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//codepen.io/assets/reset/normalize.css">

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/5.5.0/css/foundation.css'>



</head>

<body>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-6 columns">
      <a href="http://127.0.0.1/makine/canon-powershot-elph-310-hs/" title="Canon PowerShot Elph 310 HS">
        <img width="199" height="147" src="http://i.imgur.com/fwHd8zf.png" class="attachment-kucuk wp-post-image" alt="Canon_PowerShot_Elph_310_HS_428369_i0" />
        <h4>Canon PowerShot Elph 310 HS</h4>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-6 columns">
      <a href="http://127.0.0.1/makine/canon-powershot-s120/" title="Canon PowerShot S120">
        <img width="280" height="250" src="http://i.imgur.com/HLuFBv0.png" class="attachment-kucuk wp-post-image" alt="Canon_PowerShot_S120_890378" />
        <h4>Canon PowerShot S120</h4>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-6 columns">
      <a href="http://127.0.0.1/makine/canon-1d-x/" title="Canon 1D X">
        <img width="275" height="250" src="http://i.imgur.com/BlX05lN.png" class="attachment-kucuk wp-post-image" alt="Canon_EOS_1D_X_466261_i0" />
        <h4>Canon 1D X</h4>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-6 columns">
      <a href="http://127.0.0.1/makine/canon-7d-mark2/" title="Canon 7D Mark2">
        <img width="280" height="250" src="http://i.imgur.com/DB3cfLX.png" class="attachment-kucuk wp-post-image" alt="_3962017" />
        <h4>Canon 7D Mark2</h4>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-6 columns">
      <a href="http://127.0.0.1/makine/canon-7d/" title="Canon 7D">
        <img width="280" height="250" src="http://i.imgur.com/lOpicbY.png" class="attachment-kucuk wp-post-image" alt="Canon EOS 7D" />
        <h4>Canon 7D</h4>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-6 columns">
      <a href="http://127.0.0.1/makine/canon-70d/" title="Canon 70D">
        <img width="280" height="250" src="http://i.imgur.com/GT0t4eo.png" class="attachment-kucuk wp-post-image" alt="Canon-eos-70-d-fotograf-makinesi" />
        <h4>Canon 70D</h4>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-6 columns">
      <a href="http://127.0.0.1/makine/canon-6d/" title="Canon 6D">
        <img width="280" height="250" src="http://i.imgur.com/y2wRSZx.png" class="attachment-kucuk wp-post-image" alt="Canon 6D" />
        <h4>Canon 6D</h4>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="large-3 medium-4 small-6 columns">
      <a href="http://127.0.0.1/makine/canon-ef-50mm-f1-8-ii/" title="Canon EF 50mm f/1.8 II">
        <img width="280" height="250" src="http://i.imgur.com/5l2GjRG.png" class="attachment-kucuk wp-post-image" alt="Canon_EF_50mm_f18" />
        <h4>Canon EF 50mm f/1.8 II</h4>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's unclear what result you want in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think i see what your issue is... when it scales down the grid is breaking correct? For something like this i like to use the block grid it really comes in handy - check it out http://codepen.io/brock8282/pen/ojXZMW

also, try using equalizer for the li to make everything consistent.

```
<div class="row">

<div class="columns large-12">
  
  <ul class="small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-4">
 
<li>
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/makine/canon-powershot-elph-310-hs/" title="Canon PowerShot Elph 310 HS">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/fwHd8zf.png" class="attachment-kucuk wp-post-image" alt="Canon_PowerShot_Elph_310_HS_428369_i0">
        <h4>Canon PowerShot Elph 310 HS</h4>
        </a>
    </li>

<li>
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/makine/canon-powershot-s120/" title="Canon PowerShot S120">
            <img  src="http://i.imgur.com/HLuFBv0.png" class="attachment-kucuk wp-post-image" alt="Canon_PowerShot_S120_890378">
            <h4>Canon PowerShot S120</h4>
        </a>
    </li>

<li>
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/makine/canon-1d-x/" title="Canon 1D X">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/BlX05lN.png" class="attachment-kucuk wp-post-image" alt="Canon_EOS_1D_X_466261_i0">
            <h4>Canon 1D X</h4>
        </a>
    </li>

<li>
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/makine/canon-7d-mark2/" title="Canon 7D Mark2">
            <img  src="http://i.imgur.com/DB3cfLX.png" class="attachment-kucuk wp-post-image" alt="_3962017">
            <h4>Canon 7D Mark2</h4>
        </a>
    </li>

<li>
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/makine/canon-7d/" title="Canon 7D">
            <img  src="http://i.imgur.com/lOpicbY.png" class="attachment-kucuk wp-post-image" alt="Canon EOS 7D">
            <h4>Canon 7D</h4>
        </a>
    </li>

<li>
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/makine/canon-70d/" title="Canon 70D">
            <img  src="http://i.imgur.com/GT0t4eo.png" class="attachment-kucuk wp-post-image" alt="Canon-eos-70-d-fotograf-makinesi">
            <h4>Canon 70D</h4>
        </a>
    </li>

<li>
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/makine/canon-6d/" title="Canon 6D">
            <img  src="http://i.imgur.com/y2wRSZx.png" class="attachment-kucuk wp-post-image" alt="Canon 6D">
            <h4>Canon 6D</h4>
        </a>
    </li>

<li>
        <a href="http://127.0.0.1/makine/canon-ef-50mm-f1-8-ii/" title="Canon EF 50mm f/1.8 II">
            <img  src="http://i.imgur.com/5l2GjRG.png" class="attachment-kucuk wp-post-image" alt="Canon_EF_50mm_f18">
            <h4>Canon EF 50mm f/1.8 II</h4>
        </a>
    </li>

</ul>
  
  </div></div>
```

Comment: thank you. I converted my html code to bootstrap for this issue. Now I will use Foundation again.

Answer (score 1):

at foundation 6 blockgrid ul/li doest work you need use a single blockgrid + column system

```
<div class="row small-up-1 medium-up-2 large-up-4">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="//placehold.it/300x300" class="thumbnail" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [block grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html) component for this:

> Block grids give you a way to evenly split contents of a list within
>   the grid. If you wanted to create a row of five images or paragraphs
>   that need to stay evenly spaced no matter the screen size, the block
>   grid is for you.